# Wireshark - Facebook account

Tags: passwords, wireshark

Someone use Wireshark software, if he browse on the internet from home (using the same router) and I'm also at home, is he able to find the password of my Facebook account?

Comment: If he has access to your computer, it is easier (trivial if he has access to tools other than wireshark). If he does not, then no, the traffic is encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer: no. Facebook network traffic is encrypted by default which means someone using a tool like Wireshark will only see random characters and nothing like a password or username.

More complicated answer: there are techniques to circumvent the encryption such as SSL strip or other forms of man in the middle attacks (a type of attack where someone intercepts your network traffic). I am assuming that such attacks are not likely in the situation you describe.

Comment: Also, if the wifi is protected with **AES-CCMP** encryption which is used in **WPA2-PSK**  the client(**attacker**) can't read the traffic of another client(**you**) unless the attacker comes to know your **Temporal Encryption Key**. This case won't be valid in  TLS interception.